# ARIMA Forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, missing-data, arima

> I have a time series data which looks something like this
>    **Loan_id** **Loan_amount** **Loan_drawn_date**
>   id_001    2000000    2015-7-15
>   id_003     100       2014-7-8
>   id_009     78650     2012-12-23
>   id_990      100      2018-11-12
>
> I am trying to build a Arima forecasting model on this data which has round about 550  observations. These are the steps i have followed

Converted the time series data into daily data and replaced NA values with 0. the data look something like this

**Loan_id** **Loan_amount** **Loan_drawn_date**

id_001    2000000    2015-7-15
id_001    0          2015-7-16
id_001    0          2015-7-17
id_001    0          2015-7-18
id_001    0          2015-7-19
id_001    0          2015-7-20
....
id_003     100       2014-7-8
id_003     0       2014-7-9
id_003     0       2014-7-10
id_003     0        2014-7-11
id_003     0       2014-7-12
id_003     0       2014-7-13
....
id_009     78650     2012-12-23
id_009     0     2012-12-24
id_009     0     2012-12-25
id_009     0     2012-12-26
id_009     0     2012-12-27
id_009     0     2012-12-28
...
id_990      100      2018-11-12
id_990      0      2018-11-13
id_990      0      2018-11-14
id_990      0      2018-11-15
id_990      0      2018-11-16
id_990      0      2018-11-17
id_990      0      2018-11-18
id_990      0      2018-11-19

Can Anyone please suggest me how do i proceed ahead with these 0 values now?

Seeing the variance in the loan amount numbers i would take log of the of the loan amount. i am trying to build the ARIMA model for the first time and I have read about all the methods of imputation but there is nothing i can find. Can anyone please tell me how do i proceed ahead in this data

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.
SO is for specific programming problems; it appears that you need to work through a tutorial on Armina modeling.

Comment: @Prune--- I am a beginner in the ARIMA modelling and I am just trying to learn if the 0 values can anyhow be replaced with any number. The means and modes wont wory and that is why I posted this question here.

Comment: Building ARIMA model:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/ you can take reference of this site to build model

Comment: I think you'll get better help if you post code that attempts to deal with imputation.  As your question stands, it appears to be a request for off-site resources or comprehensive design, either of which is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly about your specific domain problem, but these things apply usually in general:

1. If the NA values represent 0 values for your domain specific problem, then replace them with 0 and then fit the ARIMA model (this would for example be the case if you are looking at daily sales and on some days you have 0 sales)
2. If the NA values represent unknown values for your domain specific problem then do not replace them and fit your ARIMA model. (this would be the case, if on a specific day the employee forgot to write down the amount of sales and it could be any number).

I probably would not use imputation at all. There are methods to fit an ARIMA model on time series that have missing values. Usually these algorithms should probably also implemented somewhere in python. (but I don't know since I am mostly using R)